# Scraping list from webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract items in 'Symbol' column for this webpage:

https://chartink.com/screener/2-short-trend

My code is like this:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

def stockList(url):
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=1)
    stock = [{item.text} for item in r.html.xpath('//*[@class="//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a"]')]
    return stock
listStock = stockList('https://chartink.com/screener/2-short-trend')
print(listStock)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kashk\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Scripts\CIscreen2pcShort.py", line 12, in <module>
    listStock = stockList('https://chartink.com/screener/2-short-trend')
  File "C:\Users\kashk\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Scripts\CIscreen2pcShort.py", line 10, in stockList
    stock = [{item.text} for item in r.html.xpath('//*[@class="//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a"]')]
  File "C:\Users\kashk\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 255, in xpath
    selected = self.lxml.xpath(selector)
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 1597, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
  File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 305, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__
  File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid predicate
```

Can you pls suggest where am I going wrong.

Also, is there a way to send this output to a dataframe.

Comment: Can you include the error output?

Answer (score 0):

File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 1597, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 305, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.**call**
File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).